Does using Rc<Cell<Option<T>>> have the same cost of Rc<RefCell<T>>?
i know that using RefCell has a runtime cost, and also i've learn that i can avoid using it by replacing it with Cell<Option<T>> or Cell<T>(T impl Default) and use take or replace to get the instance, mutate it then put it back.
but there's also some cost, i have to wrap T with Some and use if let Some(t) & .set(Some(t)) to get and put it back. i don't know if it worth replacing RefCell with Cell<Option>

Short answer. No. Just use RefCell. It clearly shows your intent to realax borrow checker and move it into runtime, and has some nicer APIs. Cell was designed to do something different. So while you can use it as you described it will be unergonomic, confusing to others and will likely result in more memory consumption.

If you want a more detailed performance review, you should show concrete code examples. What you described leaves some ambiguity, so I cannot give a more definitive answer, than above general advice.

The gist: RefCell<T> is more flexible and easier to use with fewer gotchas. It will outperform or perform at least as good as Cell<Option<T>> in most situations. It should be used unless the small size overhead is proven to be a problem (by a benchmark!)



usecase
RefCell<T>
Cell<Option<T>>
Cell<T: Default>




access with
shared: borrow()  exclusive: borrow_mut()
shared: impossible  exclusive: take()
shared: impossible (only the first take gets the real value and only last replace takes effect  exclusive: take()


access performance
has to check if the value is available and update an integer
has to check if the value is available and replace a Some(t) with None
has to use T::default() to replace the taken value which might be expensive


acess is checked
always
always (the Option is None when the value is checked out)
never, as a result, two concurrent branches might have a value and updates of either branch might be missed.


concurrent access
can hand out multiple shared references at once
not possible
not possible (the second access will only get T::default() and has no way of knowing)


releasing the value
automatic when Ref/RefMut is dropped when it goes out of scope or manually by dropping it
must remember to use replace
must remember to use replace


value release performance
decrement an integer
replace a None with Some(t)
T::drop which might be expensive


size
always a full pointer width extra that tracks how many Ref/RefMut are in circulation
typically requires a number of bytes equal to the alignment of T extra for the discriminant, or no size-overhead at all if T has a nieche that Option can use
no size overhead



So in summary, yes you can avoid using RefCell, but you'll still incur a runtime cost.
It's not unlikely to be even bigger than the small cost of RefCell. The only thing you can sometimes save on is the size overhead of one pointer width that keeps track of number of Ref[Mut]s in circulation.
